# mysql match against error

Tags: mysql, sql

my codes:

```
CREATE TABLE  `search` (
  `tablekey` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `col1` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tablekey`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `col1` (`col1`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;


INSERT INTO `search` (`tablekey`, `col1`) VALUES
(1, 'data for hello user'),
(2, 'data'),
(3, 'data user'),
(4, 'hello what is user for data');
```

now i have executed this query :

```
Select * from search where match (col1) against('hello' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

and it shows `empty set`

also see [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b0d490/1/0)

Comment: Strange, syntax is correct I believe. When you match against ('data hello' it retrieves all. but nothing if only 'hello'

Comment: also not working for `what` `is` and `for`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hello` is in the [Full-Text Stopword List](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-stopwords.html) for `MyISAM` tables.

See [Boolean Full-text Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-boolean.html)

Comment: there is not table in mysql Information schema with name INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD

Comment: Well, your table is `MyISAM` not `InnoDb` for starters.. you need the bit after the heading 'Stopwords for MyISAM Search Indexes'.

Comment: The engine used to create the table.. `ENGINE=MyISAM` in your `CREATE TABLE` code. `FULLTEXT` indices are only supported by `MyISAM` up to MySQL 5.5, `InnoDB` supports `FULLTEXT` in MySQL 5.6+.

Comment: `Server version: 5.5.37-cll - MySQL Community Server (GPL)` how can i use  `Full-Text Stopword List ` in my localserver

Comment: See the bottom answer on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9300600/no-results-after-removing-mysql-ft-stopword-file)