# MySQL searching for containing characters with FULLTEXT

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search, wildcard, sql-like

I wanted to upgrade my current SQL search query:

```
SELECT * FROM aab_movies WHERE title LIKE '%the walking%'
```

To a nicely optimized search query, something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM aab_movies WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST('+the +walking' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Both queries are working, but the 'nicely' optimized one, has one problem. Which is not retrieving the correct data. Whenever i'm searching for the walking, I only want the item which starts OR includes 'the walking'. Right now it retrieves everything which includes 'the' & 'walking' (a kind of seperation of every single word in the cell).

Could anyone explain / help me reach the outcome i'd like to have? it'll be appreciated a lot!

In short: I want to retrieve the data, which starts OR contains the (whole) string given (and not seperating every word & then compare them with the string given).

Comment: Put the value in quotes.

Comment: @chris85 How would I do this for multiple values?

Comment: Exactly. match(title) against('the walking' IN BOOLEAN MODE)

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-boolean.html `'"some words"'` - "Find rows that contain the exact phrase “some words” (for example, rows that contain “some words of wisdom” but not “some noise words”)."

Comment: @jkavalik I've readen it, but how would I be finding another value, for example 'Walking the way off', while searching for 'The Walking'?

Comment: You'd want to find `Walking the way off` when searching for `"The Walking"`?

Comment: @chris85 That may be a terrible example, but it was a quicky. Let's say i'm searching for 'The walking' everything which contains 'The walking' or begins with 'The walking' has to be shown. So for example, there is this cell 'The walking dead' and i'll be searching for 'The walking', both cells (The walking & The walking dead) have to show up.

Comment: I forgot about stop words list, see the answer below. Your current query is probably only searching for `walking`.

Comment: @chris85 The stop word list has already been deactivated, so it is pure the query it's work atm

Comment: Okay, then I think this should work as expected when using the quoted value e.g. `The walking` and `The walking dead` should be returned. Is it not?

Comment: @chris85 Well, after you've mentioned the stop words list. I tried searching for another statement, which retrieved it well. But i've already set the ft_stopword_file to empty? So i'm not sure why 'the' is being ignored. Is it because i'm using innoDB and ft_stopword_file is myISAM? (i've used ft_stopword_file because I couldn't find any alternative for innoDB)

Comment: This might be your issue, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9300600/no-results-after-removing-mysql-ft-stopword-file/9408229#9408229, specifically `FULLTEXT indexes must be rebuilt after changing this variable or the contents of the stopword file.`

Comment: @chris85 I've already repaired the table, so that's not the issue. I think the stopword somehow is still active. But after runnig the query 'show variables LIKE "ft_%"' I can clearly see that ft_stopword_file is set to empty.

Answer (score 2):

The query that you want is:

```
SELECT *
FROM aab_movies
WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST('"the walking"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

However, two cautions.  One, you have to be very careful about the minimum word length and term length.  This might preclude three-letter words (depending on the setting used when the index was built).

Second, you have to be very, very careful about the stop-words list.  A word like "the" is going to be removed automatically, so you would need adjust the stop words list.

You might consider constructing the query like this:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM (SELECT m.*
      FROM aab_movies m
      WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST('+the +walking' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
     ) m
WHERE title like '%the walking%';
```

Under many circumstances, the inner query only returns a handful of rows.  The outer query then uses `like`, but this is on such a small set of data that performance might be quite acceptable.

Comment: I think you can do the MATCH and the LIKE in the same query, just with AND.

Comment: Thank you for your time, but i've been taking a step away from the LIKE statement (since the performance on a big database is really poor). I actually like to rebuild the LIKE statement, using FULLTEXT. So basically, everything which includes or starts with the string given, has to show up.

Comment: @Testuser070 the idea behind this is that MATCH finds only a few rows which might contain what you want and the like checks only those - that way the performance does not degrade.

Comment: @jkavalik Isn't the performance better since it's using a smart range? For example the string 'The walking', it would only be searching at the range T & W right?

Comment: @Testuser070 I think fulltext index does not use ranges at all, but it definitelly can find the relevant rows faster than LIKE. Check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ff5ba/1 and http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ff5ba/2 - the first shows the problem with "the" being too short and too common word to be indexed unfortunatelly, but the second shows the idea in this answer. You can check `View Execution Plan` button to see index usage.

Comment: ft_min_word_len is set to 1, so the min length is not the issue. I think as you mentioned before (in your answer) it's the stop word list, but this one is set to empty too..

Comment: @Testuser070 . . . For InnoDB, you also have to deal with min token size:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_ft_min_token_size.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, i've managed to fix it (ofcourse by help by the people answered on this topic).

The stop words list wasn't deactivated for the engine I was using (innoDB). I've configured the my.ini, and applied the following rules

```
[mysqld]
innodb_ft_min_token_size = 1
innodb_ft_enable_stopword = ''
ft_min_word_len = 1
ft_stopword_file = ''
```

These basically, disable the stopword list & minimizes the minimum word length to 1. After doing this, you have to repair your table (if the FULLTEXT) has already been set.

```
SELECT * FROM aad_movies WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST('"the walking"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Was the query which is correct :)